# Custom_Vision_Prediction_3.0 REST API Giving 401 error

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-custom-vision

I am trying to call Custom Vision Prediction Classification RestAPI Endpoint (https://southcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/Custom_Vision_Prediction_3.0/operations/5c82db60bf6a2b11a8247c15)

I am using South Central US endpoint

I got the required Training and Prediction key from Keys section In Resource Management Azure Portal

Following is the response I am getting back if I call the Custom Vision Prediction classification RestAPI Endpoint

```
{

"error": {
"code": "401",
"message": "The ClassifyImage Operation under Custom_Vision_Prediction_3.0 API is not supported with the current subscription key and pricing tier Custom_Vision.Training.S0."
}
}
```

I can see that It saying that my current pricing tier is not supporting 3.0 API but the plan S0(Standard) costing me 0.35 USD per 1k images and my subscription plan is Pay-As-You-Go

Then Why I am getting this error?

Any help appreciated

[image]

Comment: did you double-check that you are using the Prediction key for the API call, not the training key?

Comment: @silent There is total 2 key in Keys Section of Azure Portal and I have tried with both, no luck :(

Comment: Are you sure that you are looking at the correct resource in the Azure Portal? It should show "API type: Custom Vision Prediction"

Comment: There are two resources created for you when you created Custom vision. One for Training and one for Prediction

Comment: OMG! I was not aware of that @silent So when I tried with other resources as you have mentioned it worked! Thanks :)

Comment: glad to hear it. I made an answer out of it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a Custom Vision in your Azure subscription, two resources are created for you: One for Training and one for Prediction. Each has a dedicated set of API keys.

[image]

Make sure to use the correct resource for either Training or Prediction usage.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same issue but our problem was caused by not publishing the iteration we were trying to access.

Once we published the iteration and used the prediction key the issue was resolved.